# CSS. Анимация при наведении курсора

Tags: html, css, анимация, hover, css-transform

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать анимацию, как на картинке, только при наведении мышки?  когда я использую hover, у меня отодвигается только один блок на который наведу, а нужно, чтобы при наведении мыши на любой из блоков отодвигались оба.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKf5j.png]

[https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg[![пример](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg%5B!%5B%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80) решения задачи][2]][2]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  perspective: 240px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block::before {
  content: 'Hello';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block:hover .block__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) scale(.5);
}

.block:hover .block__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotateY(-60deg) scale(.5);
}

.block__item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 0;
}

.block__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Ahmed_08 вы можете добавить свойство [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin), чтобы установить положение оси вращения дверок (Y) — сейчас они как будто слетают с петель при открытии. При этом `scale` можно заменить на `scaleX`.